# adding dictionary to csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, python-3.4

My dictionary is as follows:

```
my_d ={'2010-01-02': [0.696083, 0.617865], '2010-01-01': [0.697253, 0.618224], '2010-01-03': [0.696083, 0.617865]}
```

and i wish to output like the following:

```
DATE,EUR,GBP
2010-01-02,0.696083,0.617865
2010-01-03,0.697253,0.618224
2010-01-03,0.696083,0.617865
```

i have tried this:

```
my_list = ["date", "EUR", "GBP"]
with open(fname, 'w',newline = '') as my_csv:
csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter=',')
csv_writer.writerow(my_list)
csv_writer.writerows(my_d)
```

but the csv file looks nothing like that. Please also be aware further up in my code the user has the ability to choose how many values each key has, so in this example it has two, in another it may have three this would also mean my_list would increase in size, but i believe the first row will already cater for that, i just need help with the rest of the rows, i need it to work for any amount of keys.

Comment: What does your output actually look like?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over your dictionary items and then write to your file,also its better to use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for dealing with `csv` files :

```
my_list = ["date", "EUR", "GBP"]
import csv
my_d ={'2010-01-02': [0.696083, 0.617865], '2010-01-01': [0.697253, 0.618224], '2010-01-03': [0.696083, 0.617865]}
with open('fname.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(my_list)
    for mydate in sorted(my_d.keys()):
        spamwriter.writerow([mydate]+my_d[mydate])
```

Note the absence of `newline=''` when opening the file. This allows the file to have "normal" newline characters (usually `'\n'` or `'\r\n'`)

*Note* that as you are in python 3.x you can open the file with `w` mode!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `'w'` instead of `'wb'` so that you get automatic newline conversion?

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah, i didn't noted its python 3.x!

Comment: Everything is perfect now apart from one thing, the csv file does not output the dates in chronological order!

Comment: @StevenGhandi its because of that `dict`'s are unorderred!

Comment: Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: @StevenGhandi If you want to sort your items after extract from dictionary you can write the sorted elements, Otherwise there is no way!